# python slicing array back to front partial

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I have the following issue with slicing array's

```
test = np.arange(5,10)
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

now I want to slice from back to front with negative steps:

```
test[3:0:-1]
--> array([8, 7, 6])
```

But what I want is an output of array([8, 7, 6, 5])

Furthermore, this needs to be done in a loop, so the first time I have to slice including element[0] the second time till element[1]
What input do i need for this?

Comment: Omit the second index: `[3::-1]`

Comment: This only works in a single case, as I want to slice in a loop to element i with i ranging from element 0 to 50

Comment: _"Furthermore, this needs to be done in a loop, so the first time I have to slice including element[0] the second time till element[1] What input do i need for this?"_ Can you elaborate a bit, show an example for the looping?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
test[3:-5:-1]
```

Output:

```
[8,7,6,5]
```